# Add dynamic values in sql where clause, but its not working

Tags: sql

I am trying to add month value from the drop down list into where clause but it's not working.

If I select January month from the drop down list, then hello variable should contain that month.

I am able to extract month and storing in hello variable but it's not working with the `where` clause. Any suggestions will be appreciated

```
function tree() {
    alert("abc");
    var shortName = 'EXPDB';  
    var version = '';  
    var displayName = 'EXPENSE Database';  
    var maxSize = 2*1024*1024; //  bytes  
    EXPDB = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);  
    EXPDB.transaction(
        function (transaction) {
            var hello= $('#mchoose').val();//Contains the month value from drop down list
            alert("Wass"+hello);
            transaction.executeSql("SELECT SUM(amount1) AS OrderTotal FROM budget1 WHERE month= "+hello+" ", [], dataSelectHandler, errorHandler)
        }
     );
 }
```

Comment: What's the value of `hello`? `3` or `March`?

Comment: Contains hello the number of the month or an string representation (eg "januar")? In the latter case you have to quote the string in the statement.

Comment: First of all I am choosing January from drop down list and value of hello is January. But in where clause hello is not working. it contains string representation. How can i quote the string? And Why the above sql query is not working fine??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non-numeric values, you must wrap the values in single quotes:

```
var mySQL = "SELECT SUM(amount1) AS OrderTotal FROM budget1 WHERE month='"+hello+"'";

transaction.executeSql(mySQL, [], dataSelectHandler, errorHandler);
```

For this to work, it assumes your `month` column is of datatype `varchar`!

It appears you're taking form values and executing right against the database. Be warned: this is opening you up to a huge SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Finally I made that thing to work.
And If i have to add an integer value, like newFeature.OrderTotal has an integer value in it so how can I show it dynamically.
txt += "<td>"+newFeature.OrderTotal+"</td>";

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have created another thread for this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342865/adding-integer-value-dynamically-to-table