# Adding Integer Value dynamically to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

If I have to add an integer value, like `newFeature.OrderTotal` has an integer value in it.

How can I show it dynamically in a table that I am creating dynamically?

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

```
txt += "<td>"+newFeature.OrderTotal+"</td>";
```

How can this be done?

```
 function dataSelectHandler(transaction, results){

  // Handle the results
  for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {

    var row = results.rows.item(i);

    var newFeature = new Object();

        newFeature.OrderTotal   = row['OrderTotal'];//OrderTotal is coming from `(//"SELECT SUM(amount1) AS OrderTotal FROM budget1 WHERE month='"+hello+"' ";)`
    var q1 = newFeature.OrderTotal;//q1 has an integer value suppose 46
    alert(q1);//here alert box is showing properly value of q1
    }
}

var txt = "";
var myTable = "";
txt += "<table id='myTable' border='5'>";
txt += "<tr>";
txt += "<th>Month</th>";
txt += "<th>Amount</th>";
txt += "</tr>";
txt += "<tr>";
txt += "<td>"+$('#mchoose').val()+"</td>";
txt += "<td>"+q1+"</td>";//m not getting any values in this q1 in the table row
txt += "</tr>";
txt += "</table>";

$('#ss').html(txt);
```

Comment: Adding an individual cell to your table is probably not what you want; you'd have to add a cell at this column on each row (unless you want to ruin your table). Wouldn't it better suit your needs to add content to an existing cell?

Comment: this is not an existing cell. As I am getting integer values in newFeature.OrderTotal and I just want to display that value in the row. See my below code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a table with rows and data containing your elements, here's an example:

```
function addTable(parentElementId) {
  var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  // Create the table with a row and cell for each data element.
  var t = document.createElement("table");
  t.id = "myTable";
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var tr = t.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"))
      , td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
    td.innerHTML = data[i];
  }
  // Add the table to the given element.
  var p = document.getElementById(parentElementId);
  p.appendChild(t);
}
```

Comment: I have to change a lot of code if i am doing as you said. What I want is that value of q1 should be displayed in the table row. But it is not showing. alert box is working fine for that.

Comment: @Raihan: right, so instead of using my for-loop which goes over the "data" array, use the for-loop from your question.  Instead of setting `td.innerHTML = data[i]` use `td.innerHTML = q1`.

Comment: Thing is that when I am storing something in q2, like this var q2="Hello"; and replacing q1 with q2 then the value of q2 is displayed in that row. But not with q1..

Comment: @Raihan: please consider editing your question to include more detailed information - the more specifics you include the better the quality of the answers you will get.

Answer (score 0):

If this idea suitable to your problem, then you can get the code:

(1) Add the table in the #ss html directly statically or just like your own way from jquery $("#ss").html(tableText). note the right tag hierarchy is `table > tbody > tr > td`, Since `tr` and `td` is dynamic. so only add `table` and `tbody`.

(2) In your `dataSelectHandler()` `for` loop, build your string in format `"<tr><td>"+newFeature.OrderTotal+"</td></tr>"` and append to tbody like this `$("#myTable > tbody").html(rowText);` to replace the `alert();`.